# How to make an app a default for a certain task?

Tags: android

I'm in a mobile programming class right now  and we have to make a simple media player. Right now I'm trying to make it so that when a user opens an mp3 my app comes up as a possible default? How do I code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make an app a default for a certain task?

*You* can't "make an app a default". The *user* makes it their default.

> Right now I'm trying to make it so that when a user opens an mp3 my app comes up as a possible default? How do I code this?

Try the following `<intent-filter>` on your activity that sets up the media playback:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Then, if some app fires off an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on an MP3 file, your activity should appear along with other activities from other apps in a chooser dialog.